# Does Google AMP Cache guarantee that it won’t create link rot?

Tags: amp-html, google-cdn

[Google AMP Cache](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/) is a service that serves cached versions of AMP pages via URLs in this format:

```
// original URL
https://amp.theguardian.com/football/2016/aug/23/roma-champions-league-porto-dundalk  

// cached version on Google AMP Cache
https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/amp.theguardian.com/football/2016/aug/23/roma-champions-league-porto-dundalk
```

**Live demo:** [original URL](https://amp.theguardian.com/football/2016/aug/23/roma-champions-league-porto-dundalk), [cashed version on Google AMP Cache](https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/amp.theguardian.com/football/2016/aug/23/roma-champions-league-porto-dundalk).

Does Google guarantee that this service will be available (virtually) forever? (I haven’t found any mention of this in the docs and FAQ.) I’m asking because if Google were to shut it down, that would create a fair amount of link rot, since various parties (including end users) may rely on these AMP Cache URLs.

---

[Related discussion on Twitter](https://twitter.com/helloanselm/status/755277325256785920).

---

**Update:** I have updated the example with real URLs.

Answer (score 4):

We recommend that people link to the canonicals not to the Google AMP Cache versions of their pages. That prevents the link-rot problem you've described.

We also published (yesterday) a set of [design principles](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/8502985a91efb499e454a89bbfd63f16e4415500/DESIGN_PRINCIPLES.md) which say that things should work without the cache as well as with the cache.

Comment: It prevents the problem only on an instance-per-instance basis. But some users have shared and will share AMP Cache URLs in the future. The only true solution is that Google never shuts down the `https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/` service (or at least downgrades it to an auto-redirect service instead of shutting it down completely). If Google cannot guarantee that, AMP Cache will continue to be a potential link rot problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the AMP cache URL directly? If you need to update cache or remove a url from the cache to prevent link rot, use the [AMP cache ping url](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping).

Linking to the Cache version directly will cause issues if the AMP cache is ever unavailable. If someone has bookmarked that cache URL it might not exist in the future. You need to leave the decision to send a user to the AMP verions up to Google.

When all is said and done you would have two version of every page you want AMP'd. You'll have the regular version and the AMP version. The regular version has a canonical link tag to point to the AMP version and vice-versa. [Read more on making your AMP pages discoverable](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery). When the AMP canonical is not present in the head tag of the regular page Google assumes there is no AMP version and therefore you stay right where you're at. If that AMP canonical DOES exist, AMP will try to server a cached version otherwise it will send you directly to the AMP canonical.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn’t about me - I neither have access to AMP (I’m in Croatia) nor do I publish AMP pages. Rather, this is about a broader issue. When a user opens an AMP page from Google Search results, they will see the version hosted on `google.com/amp/`. When that user then decides to share that page, they will copy-paste (or otherwise use) that Google URL. Do you see the issue? The way the system currently works, Google URLs inevitably end up being shared by users. If Google were to shut down `google.com/amp/`, all these shared links would become link rot. Google must **guarantee** never to do that.

Comment: Does Goggle guarantee anything? I'm assuming that Google has thought of this scenario and I doubt Google.com/amp is going anywhere.